# Outlook rule that applies only to original message

Tags: outlook

I have a rule that searches through a body message and looks for a phrase. If the phrase is found the message is categorized. Works fine except I need the rule to only categorize the original message and not any messages that are replies to that message.

Is this possible via rules?

Answer (score 1):

No, a rule can't recognize whether a message is an original/initial one or not (the first from the conversation).

But I'd suggest using VBA macros instead. You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

So, you may get an instance of the `MailItem` object and use the [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method which obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs.

```
Sub DemoConversationTable() 
 Dim oConv As Outlook.Conversation 
 Dim oTable As Outlook.Table 
 Dim oRow As Outlook.Row 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Const PR_STORE_ENTRYID As String = _ 
 "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFB0102" 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 ' Obtain the current item for the active inspector. 
 Set oMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
 
 If Not (oMail Is Nothing) Then 
 ' Obtain the Conversation object. 
 Set oConv = oMail.GetConversation 
 If Not (oConv Is Nothing) Then 
 Set oTable = oConv.GetTable 
 oTable.Columns.Add (PR_STORE_ENTRYID) 
 Do Until oTable.EndOfTable 
 Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow 
 ' Use EntryID and StoreID to open the item. 
 Set oItem = Application.session.GetItemFromID( _ 
 oRow("EntryID"), _ 
 oRow.BinaryToString(PR_STORE_ENTRYID)) 
 Debug.Print oItem.Subject, _ 
 "Attachments.Count=" & oItem.Attachments.count 
 Loop 
 End If 
 End If 
End Sub
```

The [Conversation.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation.gettable) method returns a `Table` object that contains rows that represent all items in the conversation. So, you may get the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

If the reply include "Re: " in the subject... you can use it as an EXCLUDE rule option (This is the 3rd checkbox list when you create a rule)